# First time scrape amazon deals that is possibly AJAX

Tags: python, ajax, web-scraping, scrapy

As a first time scrapy user, I am hoping be able to scrape deal information on Amazon.com, more specifically this page: http://www.amazon.com/Cyber-Monday/b/ref=sv_gb_2?ie=UTF8&node=5550342011&gb_hero_f_100=p:1,c:all,s:missed.

Sorry, I wish I could post a screen shot here, but I don't have reputation.

**I want to extract all of the deal item information (the title, price, % off of each 7 deals and other deals by clicking "next" button on the page) under the "upcoming" and "missed deals" section, and I tried scrapy simply using my code as follows but it was no luck. My thinking of the potential problems are:**

(1) I defined wrong xpath in either "rules" or "parse_items" (which is possible, but not likely because I copied xpath using chrome developer)

(2) The site is running in AJAX, which would then probe me to use Selenium as other threads suggested.

Here is my code:

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.http import Request
from scrapy.selector import Selector, HtmlXPathSelector
from selenium import selenium
from deal.items import DealItem

class Dealspider(BaseSpider):
    name = 'deal'
    allowed_domains = ['amazon.com']
    start_urls = ['http://www.amazon.com/b/ref=br_imp_ara-1?_encoding=UTF8&node=5550342011&pf_rd_m=ATVPDKIKX0DER&pf_rd_s=desktop-hero-2&pf_rd_r=16WPRNKJ91B97JW7TQ27&pf_rd_t=36701&pf_rd_p=1990071642&pf_rd_i=desktop']
    rules = (Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=('//td[@id="missed_filter"]'),restrict_xpaths=('//a[starts-with(@title,"Next ")]',)),callback='parse_items') , Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=('//td[@id="upcoming_filter"]'), restrict_xpaths=('//a[starts-with(@title,"Next ")]',)), callback='parse_items_2') )

def __init__(self):
    CrawlSpider.__init__(self)
    self.verificationErrors = []
    self.selenium = selenium("localhost", 4444, "*chrome", "http://www.amazon.com")
    self.selenium.start()

def __del__(self):
    self.selenium.stop()
    print self.verificationErrors
    CrawlSpider.__del__(self)
```

## parse for missed deal

```
def parse_items(self, response):
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    pdt = hxs.select('//ul[@class="ulResized pealdshoveler"]')
    sel = self.selenium
    sel.open(response.url) #I don't know where the url is
    items = []
    for t in pdt:
        item = dealItem()
        item ["missedproduct"] = t.select('//li[contains(@id,"dealTitle")]/a/@title').extract()
        item ["price"] = t.select('//li[contains(@id,"dealDealPrice")]/b').extract()
        item ["percentoff"] = t.select('//li[contains(@id,"dealPercentOff")]/span').extract()
        items.append(item)
    return items
```

## parse for upcoming deal#

```
def parse_items_2(self, response):
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    pdt = hxs.select('//ul[@class="ulResized pealdshoveler"]')
    itemscurrent = []
    for t in pdt:
        item = dealItem()
        item ["c_product"] = t.select('//li[contains(@id,"dealTitle")]/a/text()').extract()
        item ["c_price"] = t.select('//li[contains(@id,"dealDealPrice")]/b').extract()
        item ["c_percentoff"] = t.select('//li[contains(@id,"dealPercentOff")]/span').extract()
        items.append(item)
    return itemscurrent
```

At this moment, scrapy returns me nothing, and I am simply desperate to work this problem out myself, I hope you all who are smarter to help me out.

Whatever insights you have, please put it here, it would be greatly appreciated!! =) Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I confirm you that Selenium would be an approach to scrape it.

Here it is a partial solution, you can work on, to find the deals and print the title:

```
class AmazonSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "amazon"
    allowed_domains = ['amazon.com']
    start_urls = ['http://www.amazon.com/b/ref=br_imp_ara-1?_encoding=UTF8&node=5550342011&pf_rd_m=ATVPDKIKX0DER&pf_rd_s=desktop-hero-2&pf_rd_r=16WPRNKJ91B97JW7TQ27&pf_rd_t=36701&pf_rd_p=1990071642&pf_rd_i=desktop']

    def __init__(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()

    def parse(self, response):
        self.driver.get(response.url)
        for element in self.driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('a.titleLink'):
            print element.text


        self.driver.close()
```

Result would be:

*Up to 50% Off Select Hasbro Toys

Over 45% Off the Canon PowerShot S110 Digital Camera

Up to 60% Off Digital Cameras for Kids

"Dragon Age Inquisition"*

I suggest you to read the Selenium documentation to simulate the user pressing the "next" link
(http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains)

Comment: Hi Aberna, in fact I have been away and I just came back realizing that I have almost forgot what I wrote. What you are suggesting is that I include "from selenium import webdriver" into the document I already have, and start from there? Thank you for your help!

Comment: Hi, the class I wrote was an add on to your code. So make the import of the webdriver and start from there. For an improvement of your solution as to have access to all results of amazon you will have to make usage of the action chain to create a method to activate the "more results" link once the page is full loaded.  In any case if it fits your needs please accept the answer.